# Retrieved data from firebase v9 is undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-redux, reduce, dispatch

When retrieving data and `console.log` it, the data shows perfectly, but when trying to dispatch the action with the argument as a data it turns out to be `undefined`.

I tried to use await before `dispatch` the action, but it didn't change anything. Why does it happen?

[image: data is undefined]

**actions.js**

```
import * as types from './actionTypes'
import { db } from '../firebase';
import { collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";

const getFeedbacksStart = () => ({
    type: types.GET_FEEDBACKS_START,
});

const getFeedbacksSussess = (feedbacks) => ({
    type: types.GET_FEEDBACKS_SUCCESS,
    payload: feedbacks
});

const getFeedbacksFail = () => ({
    type: types.GET_FEEDBACKS_FAIL,
});


export const getFeedbacks = () => {
    return async function (dispatch) {
        dispatch(getFeedbacksStart());

        try {
            const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "feedbacks"));
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data())
            });

            const feedbacks = querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => doc.data());

            dispatch(getFeedbacksSussess(feedbacks))


        } catch (error) {
            dispatch(getFeedbacksFail(error))
        }
    }
}
```

**actionTypes.js**

```
export const GET_FEEDBACKS_START = 'GET_FEEDBACKS_START';
export const GET_FEEDBACKS_SUCCESS = 'GET_FEEDBACKS_SUCCESS';
export const GET_FEEDBACKS_FAIL = 'GET_FEEDBACKS_FAIL';
```

**reducer.js**

```
import * as types from './actionTypes'

const initialState = {
    feedbacks: {},
    loading: false,
    error: null,
};

const feedbackReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case types.GET_FEEDBACKS_START:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true
            }
        case types.GET_FEEDBACKS_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                feedbacks: action.payload,
            }
        case types.GET_FEEDBACKS_FAIL:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                error: action.payload,
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }

}

export default feedbackReducer;
```

**root-reducer.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";

import feedbackReducer from "./reducer";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    data: feedbackReducer, 
});

export default rootReducer;
```

**store.js**

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import logger from 'redux-logger';

import rootReducer from './root-reducer';
  
const store = configureStore({
    reducer: rootReducer,
    middleware: [thunk, logger],
});

export default store;
```

**ListRecord.js** where I dispatch the action

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useContext } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { getFeedbacks } from "../redux/actions";


const ListRecord = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState({});
    console.log("data", data);

    const state = useSelector(state => state.data);
    console.log("state =>", state);

    let dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getFeedbacks());
    }, [])



    return (
        <>

        </>
    );
};

export default ListRecord;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what I was doing wrong. I tried to retrieve the data in the wrong way. I was trying to use `forEach` method on a collection. Firstly, it needed to refer to the docs inside a db -> `querySnapshot.docs` and then you can use `.map()` method and loop through the whole collection you have inside your database.

The example of how to do it right with firebase v9 is [HERE](https://dev.to/abhisheks12/read-data-from-firebase-firestore-v9-28be)

Here is a working code :)

In **actions.js**

```
export const getFeedbacks = () => {
    return function (dispatch) {
        dispatch(getFeedbacksStart())

        const getData = async () => {
            try {
                const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "feedbacks"));
                const feedbacks = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
                    ...doc.data(),
                    id: doc.id
                }))
                dispatch(getFeedbacksSussess(feedbacks));

            } catch (error) {
                dispatch(getFeedbacksFail(error))
            }

        }
        getData();
    }
}
```